# How to implement infinite scroll in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, infinite-scroll

I have a large collection of image thumbnails stored in mongodb which I would like to render on a client using infinite scroll technique: show the first batch of images (i.e. 4 rows of them) and when user scrolls down to the last row in the batch, send a new batch of content to the client.

Is it possible to implement this using meteor?

Answer (score 4):

Use data-uri driven images.

```
Images.insert({data:image.toBase64()});
```

The template could look like:

```
<img id="{{_id}}" src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{{data}}}"></img>
```

And the output would look like:

```
<img id="..." src="data:image/jpg;base64,iVBO..."></img>
```

To create this effect:

1. Generate the images in a hidden container.
2. Register a DOM Mutation Observer (e.g., with `observer-summary`) that fires whenever an image is added to the hidden container.
3. When the DOM Mutation Observer detects a new image element placed into the container:

   1. Duplicate the element into a visible `Masonry` container, or any conventional method used to make an infinite scrolling container of images.
4. When the user scrolls to the bottom of the page:

   1. Update the list of images that should appear. This will reactively load the images into a hidden container.
   2. ...which will reactively place them into your visible container.

With this procedure, you don't have to write any complicated `Meteor.template.rendered` code.

Alternatively,

```
Meteor.autorun(function() {
    var visibleImages = Session.get("newImages");
    _.each(visibleImages,function(image) {
        $("#container").append("<img src='" +image.data + "'></img>");
    });
})
```

...and put documents into the `newImages` session variable whenever there are new images.

Comment: Many thanks for quick answer! Let me try which way is better for me. One more question: am I right that Mutation Observers are not implemented in IE?

Comment: `observer-summary` uses Mutation Events, I think, as a fallback.